# Operator norm of shift operator for finite measure spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory

Let $\nu$ be a *finite* Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define the shift operator $T_a$ on $L^p_{\nu}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by $f\to f(x+a)$ for some fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$.  Suppose moreover that 
$\nu$ is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure $m$ and let
$
\frac{d \nu}{dm}(x)= h(x).
$

In this case, can we obtain a bound on $\|T_{a}\|_{\mathrm{op}}$ in terms of $h$ and of $a$?

Usually when $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure then this is commonly known to be $1$, but here, in the finite and dominated case I can't seem to find such a result...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, for large $a$ the norm goes to infinity. Find a ball $B$ such that $\nu(B) > \nu(\mathbb{R}^n) - \epsilon$ and consider the characteristic function of $B$ shifted by $-a$, for any $a$ greater than the radius of $B$. Its $L^2$ norm is at most $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, but after shifting by $a$ its norm is $> \sqrt{\nu(B)}$.

For general $a$ it's just a matter of comparing $h$ and its shift by $a$. The issue is if $f$ is the characteristic function of a tiny ball $B_1$ (tiny compared to $a$), and $B_2$ is the shift of this ball by $a$, then the ratio of the square roots of $s = \int_{B_2} h$ to $r = \int_{B_1} h$ gives a lower bound on the norm of the shift. Tiny balls are all we need to look at by a short argument using Lebesgue density. So the norm of the shift will be $\sqrt{\left\|\frac{h_a}{h}\right\|_\infty}$, where $h_a$ is the shift of $h$ by $a$. (Note that this could be infinite.)

Comment: As a lower bound (when $\alpha \neq 0$) was always have 1, since the translation operator is hypercyclic no?

Comment: By $\alpha$ do you mean $a$? Then yes, 1 is always a lower bound.

Comment: I've been thinking about it but is even possible to have a probability measure $\nu$ and some $a \in \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$ for which $\sqrt{\frac{\|h_a\|}{\|h\|}_{\infty}}$ achieves value $1$?  I think it's not possible..

Comment: No, not possible. Whatever $a$ is, you can find a positive measure ball which is small enough that it is disjoint from its translation by $a$. So if you translate it by $na$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ you get an infinite sequence of disjoint sets and finiteness of $\nu$ implies that they can't all have the same measure.

Comment: But it's easy enough to come up with an $h$ such that the norms tend to $1$ as $a \to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

You get a rather obvious bound for $\|T_a\|_{op}$ from
$$ \int|f(x+a)|^p h(x)dx =\int |f(y)^p|h(y-a)dy = \int |f(y)|^ph(y) \left|h(y-a)/h(y)\right|dy \le c\int|f(y)|^ph(y)dy$$ with $c=\|h(y-a)/h(y)\|_\infty$.

Comment: I accepted Nik's result only because it has a couple more details but both a great! :)

Comment: Moreover, Nick was faster than me.

Comment: Right, but you were both faster than me.

Answer (score 2):

This was intended as an extended comment but started to have too many formulas, so I thought that it would be more legible if posted as an answer.
(You don't actually state if there are $\nu$-null sets which are not Lebesgue null, so I'm going to build an example which is mutually absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure.)

If $h$ is unbounded then it seems to me that your shift operator could be unbounded. You don't specify whether you want $p$ to be in the reflexive range, so let me take $p=2$ just to be sure, and take $n=1$, $a=1$ for simplicity.
Take $h(x)=|x|^{-3/4}$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ and $h(x)=e^{-|x|}$ outside that interval, so that $h \in L^1_m({\bf R})$. Put $d\nu = h\ dm$, so that $\nu$ is a finite measure on ${\bf R}$.

Consider 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}(x-1)^{-1/3} & \hbox{if $x\in (1,2]$} \\ 0 & \hbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
This belongs to $L^2_\nu({\bf R})$ since
$$ \int_{\bf R} |f(x)|^2 h(x) \,dx = \int_1^2 (x-1)^{-2/3} e^{-x}\,dx <\infty $$
On the other hand, 
$$ (T_1f)(x) =f(x+1) = \begin{cases} x^{-1/3} & \hbox{if $x\in (0,1]$} \\ 0 & \hbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
so
$$ \int_{\bf R} |T_1f(x)|^2 h(x) \,dx = \int_0^1 x^{-2/3} x^{-3/4}\,dx = +\infty $$

Comment: This is a very interesting point Yemon.  I didn't notice it for example...

Comment: I could have said this in a similar style to Nik Weaver's answer: the basic issue is that translation is good for Lebesgue measure because you don't change the "mass" assigned to a given region when you translate it. But as soon as some regions have "a lot more $\nu$-mass than Lebesgue mass" you are going to run into trouble by shifting an $f$-shaped pile of soil from regions with small $\nu$-mass to a place which has large $\nu$-mass

Comment: Actually, your example was very illustrative since I mistakenly has a Gaussian measure visualized (which of-course has no blowups).  Thanks a lot! :)