# Constructing a small Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ function.  Is it possible to (explicitly construction) a function $h$ such that:

- $0<h(x)$.
- $\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |h(x)|<\infty$,
- $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|h\circ u(x)|}{h(x)}=1$.

This generalizes [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362250/operator-norm-of-shift-operator-for-finite-measure-spaces/362260?noredirect=1#comment913365_362260) post the case where $u(x)=u+a$.

Comment: Ratio being 1 is too strong. Suppose $u(x) = x + a$. This would mean that on any sequence $x_0 + n a$ the value of $h$ is non-increasing. This contradicts the finiteness of total mass of $h$. To have any chance of the construction working the $\sup$ has to be bounded by something strictly greater than 1.

Comment: For ratio being $\gamma > 1$, consider $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $u(x) = x/\gamma$. This implies that $h(x/\gamma) \leq \gamma h(x)$. This implies that $h(\gamma^n x_0) \geq \gamma^{-n} h(x_0)$. This suggests that $h$ must decay like $1/x$, and hence be not integrable.